# ItemsControl ScrollViewer return to initial position after scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, itemscontrol, scrollviewer

I am adding a `ScrollViewer` to `ItemsControl` whose `ItemTemplate` is generated dynamically.

The problem is the `ScrollViewer`snaps back to its initial position after scrolling. I tried setting the grid container `Grid.Row="1"` in which the `ScrollViewer` lies so that it has enough height or set it auto but the problem persist. What am I missing?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameLevel, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}">
                <Run Text="GAME "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding CurrentGame}"/>
                <Run Text=" / "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding TotalGame}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}">
                <Run Text="{Binding CurrentTime, Converter={StaticResource SecondsToMinutesHour}}"/>   
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Margin="9,-7,9,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}">
                <Run Text="{Binding TotalTime, Converter={StaticResource SecondsToMinutesHour}}"/>
            </TextBlock>

            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="ProgressBar" Value="{Binding ProgressBarTime}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Tag="{Binding Index}" Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded">
                        <Button Width="{Binding Side}" 
                               Height="{Binding Side}" 
                               Background="{Binding BgColor}"                                   
                               Tag="{Binding Index}"
                            Content="{Binding Index}"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"
                               Click="Button_Click">

                            <ia:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <ia:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                                    <tr:SetCanvasPropertiesAction Left="{Binding Left}" Top="{Binding Top}" />
                                </ia:EventTrigger>
                            </ia:Interaction.Triggers>                               
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>         
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="adGrid" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

edit:
Ok, the real problem is, that the ItemsPnaelTemplate is a Canvas. The canvas always has Height=0 and Width=0. Items that are placed in the canvas can be bigger, but are still inside the canvas. The scrollviewer only has the Height of the canvas as an idea on how much it should be able to scroll. 
You can easily test this by temporarily setting the height of the canvas:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <Canvas Height="1500"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

And you will see, that now you can scroll.

Unfortunately I can't think of a solution right now. (Maybe setting the width and height of the `itemsControl` through code behind by calculating the needed width and height to dispay all items, by taking the items with the highest value for (Top + Side) as `Height` and (Left + Side) for `Width`)

original:

Your ContentPanel `Grid` has this `Height="Auto"`. So the ContentPanel is the same Height as the ScrollViewer and all of it's content and the actual scrolling that you can still do is just the bouncing effect of the ScrollViewer when you get to the end of it's scrolling ability.

Just delete `Height="Auto"` and you should be fine.

Comment: The code was without the `Height="Auto"` before and it didn't work. I delete it again to confirm and still does not work.

Comment: You are right. I figured this out before you edited your answer. I fix it by binding canvas height `<Canvas Height="{Binding CanvasHeight}"/>`. `CanvasHeight` is calculated by adding Top + Side of the items. Now the scrollviewer works as required.